# libstdc++ std::throw_with_nested() requires polymorphic types

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, clang, libc++

consider the following (I think illegal) code:

```
#include <exception>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    try {
        try {
            throw string ("x");
        }
        catch(string& x)
        {
            throw_with_nested(string("xx"));
        }
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        auto ep = current_exception();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

with clang++ compiled against libc++ this code compiles.

with g++ against libstdc++:

```
In file included from /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/exception:153:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/nested_exception.h: In instantiation of â��static const std::nested_exception* std::__get_nested_helper<_Ex>::_S_get(const _Ex&) [with _Ex = std::basic_string<char>]â��:
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/nested_exception.h:104:51:   required from â��const std::nested_exception* std::__get_nested_exception(const _Ex&) [with _Ex = std::basic_string<char>]â��
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/nested_exception.h:138:38:   required from â��void std::throw_with_nested(_Ex) [with _Ex = std::basic_string<char>]â��
main.cpp:15:43:   required from here
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/nested_exception.h:90:59: error: cannot dynamic_cast â��& __exâ�� (of type â��const class std::basic_string<char>*â��) to type â��const class std::nested_exception*â�� (source type is not polymorphic)
       { return dynamic_cast<const nested_exception*>(&__ex); }
                                                           ^
```

As I understand it, `std::throw_with_nested<T>` requires that T is polymorphic, and std::string is not polymorphic. So libstdc++ is doing the Right Thing(tm) here.

Anyone have anything to offer here?

Comment: Your "Am I right?" and "Anyone have anything to offer here?" remind me of the what not to ask part of the help section. Maybe reformulate to "Which implementation is correct?"

Comment: OK thanks for the pointers. Also, the duplicate gives the answer - libstdc++ is wrong as of 2011. Many thanks everyone.

Comment: According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/throw_with_nested), the only constraint is for T to be copy-constructible [here, T = std::string]. It looks like a bug in g++/libstdc++.

Comment: @Howard The original title is correct - he thinks *libc++* is being too *permissive*; turns out *libstdc++* is being too *restrictive*.

Comment: @T.C.:  Thanks for the clarification.  I skimmed too quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> N3337 [except.nested]/5,6
>
> ```
> [[noreturn]] template <class T> void throw_with_nested(T&& t);
> ```
>
> Let `U` be `remove_reference<T>::type`. 
>  5. Requires: `U` shall be
>   `CopyConstructible`. 
>  6. Throws: if `U` is a non-union class type not
>   derived from `nested_exception`, an exception of un-specified type that is publicly derived from both `U` and `nested_exception` and constructed from `std::forward<T>(t)`, otherwise `std::forward<T>(t)`.

Also consider that `nested_exception` is polymorphic as it has a virtual destructor ([except.nested]/2):

> [ Note: `nested_exception` has a virtual destructor to make it a
>   polymorphic class. Its presence can be tested for with `dynamic_cast`.
>   — end note ]

The  exception-type that is actually thrown is always polymorphic. `U` doesn't have to be, though - just `CopyConstructible`, as noted by the Requires-section.

So libstdc++ has an invalid implementation. It should internally specialize for types for which `is_base_of<nested_exception, U>::value` is `false`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Another reason to be happy that I moved our entire code base to clang/libc++.

Comment: @RichardHodges Clang is the best.